# How to check big video file if can't check it entirely?

Tags: malware, antivirus, detection, scan, video

There size limit on VirusTotal, some videos are very big. What if cut off part from the video and send part of it. Is it possible? What part of it, where malware can be?

Answer (score 1):

Most file formats (such as videos) aren't going to execute code unless:

1. The file is somehow a valid executable and you purposefully execute it
2. The application viewing it (e.g. a video player) has a specific vulnerability, and the file contains crafted content to exploit that specific vulnerability

In either case, there is no way to give you an answer without knowing exactly what type of malware. For instance, #2 could be a vulnerability in the video header, or the video data itself, which could be any part of the file.

In general, if you aren't trying to execute a video file and your video player is up to date, you probably don't need to check your video files for malware.

Comment: I guess he means the second case. He can try to heuristically scan the file for chunks looking like x86 code and send to virustotal only these chunks. Though I am not sure that AVs are able scan for code outside of executable formats.

Comment: @KOLANICH but antiviruses scan everything, if they not able then why they do this?

Comment: @RS sure, they may "scan" everything, but that doesn't mean they know how to interpret and identify everything. "Scanning" could be as simple as comparing a hash of the file to a list of known malicious files.